# Determining an automorphism, when a composition of two automorphisms and the other automorphism is given

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, function-and-relation-composition, automorphism-group

Let $\phi$ be an automorphism of an abelian finite group, say $G$ and $s,t$ be the generating elements of $G$.

When we know the values $\phi(s), \phi(t)$, then we can find the value of any element under $\phi$. In other words, when we know where the generating elements are mapped, we know the entire automorphism.

Suppose $\theta$ is another automorphism of $G$. Suppose we don't know $\theta(s), \theta(t)$. But we know $\theta(\phi(s)), \theta(\phi(t)), \phi(s), \phi(t)$.

Knowing $\theta(\phi(s)), \theta(\phi(t))$, is like knowing the where the generating elements are mapped under the composition automorphism $\theta \phi$.

Then using this information how can I determine, $\theta$?

(Determine $\theta(s), \theta(t)$ ?)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: To determine $\theta(g)$, you find the unique element $h \in G$ such that $\phi(h)=g$, and then $\theta(g) = \theta(\phi(h))$. Since you are assuming that $G$ is finite, you can do this by exhaustive searching. Of course there might be more efficient ways of doing it, depending on how $G$ is defined.

Comment: Thank you very much, @DerekHolt :)

Comment: Dear @DerekHolt in a similar question suppose I know how $\theta$ is defined but not about $\phi$, not even the generating elements $s,t$. Then when I know $\theta(\phi(s)), \theta(\phi(t)), \phi(s),\phi(t)$ is there a way I can determine about $\phi$? Suppose $G=\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$, where $p$ is a prime and $|s|=|t|=p$, but just knowing $\phi(s),\phi(t)$ without knowing the generating elements $s,t$ doesn't help to determine the homomorphism $\phi$, right?

Comment: If it is known, the generating elements and where the generating elements are mapped under $\phi$, then the entire homomorphism can be determined right? But from above details can't determine $\phi(g)$ for any $g \in G$?

Comment: If $\phi$ is an automorphism of $G$ and $s$ and $t$ generate $G$, then so do $\phi(s)$ and $\phi(t)$. So $\theta$ is fully determined from the knowledge of $\theta(\phi(s))$ and $\theta(\phi(t))$.

Comment: Yes @DerekHolt but if in another case we don't know about $\phi$, but I'm only given $\theta(\phi(s)), \theta(\phi(t)), \phi(s), \phi(t)$ and $\theta$. Now I don't need to know about $\theta$. But I want to find $\phi$. The elements $s,t$ is also not given. Is there a way to find $\phi$ too?

Comment: No, from the information given, $\phi$ could be any automorphism of $G$.

Comment: Okay, thank you very very much @DerekHolt